# Azure devops : Approvals and checks on a repository level

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-repos

I'm using the Approvals and checks for the releases and builds with no problem,
and I was surprised to see this feature on a repository level.
[image]
Any idea on the added value to do it on repo level ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`Approvals and checks`** feature on Azure Git repositories can be used to control which pipelines can access which repositories.

The common use case is [**Repository resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#repository-resource) in the YAML pipelines.

For more details about this feature, you can reference the following documents:

- [**Repos as a protected resource in YAML pipelines**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-186-update#repos-as-a-protected-resource-in-yaml-pipelines)
- [**Protect a repository resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/repository-resource?view=azure-devops)

Comment: thank you for your clear and precise answer